# Strange method declaration with []

Tags: java

I found this method declaration

```
public Integer getAllInts() [] {
```

Notice that [] at the end, what does it mean? This method `returns null;` in my code, but when I try to return an Integer from it, it gives following compilation error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to Integer[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, answer is in your question itself, see compilation error. This is nothing but **method variant of array declaration**. This method will return an array of Integers.

Java gives flexibility to declare array by adding [] after name of the variable, like `int a []`, same is the case with methods.

This declaration is similar to :

```
public Integer[] getAllInts() {
```